# Android Edit ArrayAdapter row inline

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, edit

I have a ListActivity which uses an ArrayAdapter To display the rows.
I want to edit the rows inline, to be precise I want to toggle the text in one of the Views when ever User Clicks on the View. Eg. If the TextView Value id "Complete" it will become "Incomplete" and Visa versa.

But the problem is , the row tvstate value is **always the value of the last row** and not the one which is clicked.

Am I missing something basic. Please help as I am very new to Android development.

EDIT : Even a mechanism to Update the same row in the Adapter will be of help, if not inline edit.

Here is my code for the Adapter.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,final ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout_cpe, null);
    }
    CPEDetails dt = items.get(position);
    if (dt != null) {
        tvSNo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.serialNumber);
        tvState = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.state);
        if (tvSNo != null && tvState != null) {
        tvSNo.setText(dt.getVc_serial());
        tvState.setText(dt.getState());

        }
    }

    tvState.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        tvState.setText(tvState.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Completed")?"Incomplete":"Completed");
        Utility.i("On Click State ::"+position);

        CPEDetails cpe = new CPEDetails();
        cpe.setVc_serial(tvSNo.getText().toString());
        cpe.setState(tvState.getText().toString());
        items.set(position, cpe);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });


    btnDelete = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        items.remove(position);

        notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return v;

    }
```

Comment: `    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    //tvState.setText(tvState.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Completed")?"Incomplete":"Completed");
  Utility.i("On Click State ::"+position);
  
  CPEDetails cpe = new CPEDetails();
  cpe=items.get(position);
  //cpe.setVc_serial(cpe.get);
  cpe.setState(cpe.getState().equalsIgnoreCase("Completed")?"Incomplete":"Completed");
  items.set(position, cpe);
  notifyDataSetChanged();
     }`

Answer (score 0):

this is because the Custom Adapter you are using is missing some parts.

It should look like :

```
    ViewHolder holder; 
    View v = convertView;
    holder = null;

    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder(); 
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout_cpe, null);
        holder.tvSNo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.serialNumber);
        holder.tvState = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.state);

        v.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

    CPEDetails dt = items.get(position);
    if (dt != null) {

        if (tvSNo != null && tvState != null) {
        holder.tvSNo.setText(dt.getVc_serial());
        holder.tvState.setText(dt.getState());

        }

    }

    class ViewHolder { 
        TextView tvSNo;
        TextView tvState;
    }
```

... the rest of the setonclicklistener code ...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using tvSNo and tvState as fields of adapter' class. And every call of getView(...) is rewriting these fields, so after last call tvState and tbSNo holds the last visible row of the list. 
Try to use ViewHolder pattern, here is the Romain Guy presentation from Google IO: http://youtu.be/N6YdwzAvwOA?t=2m. Also there are a lot of examples (http://goo.gl/YV6xaA - here is first one from fast google search)